# Jordan/Lebesgue measure of $A\times B$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A \subset \mathbb R^n, B \subset \mathbb R^m$.

I have already showed that if $A$ is bounded and $B$ has Jordan/Lebesgue measure zero, then $A\times B$ has Jordan/Lebesgue measure zero.

However, does the statement hold if $A$ is not bounded? Give a proof or a counterexample.

Comment: Where does your proof rely on the boundedness of $A$?

Comment: $A$ is bounded, so it can be covered by a rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still holds. Just write $A$ as countable union of bounded subset. Countable union of measure zero set is still measure zero.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Let $A_n = A \cap B_n$, where $B_n$ is the open ball center at the origin with radius $n$. Since you can show that $A_n \times B$  is measure zero for any $n$, then so is the union of $A_n \times B$.

Comment: But this is only for Lebesgue, right? Since any finite union of Jordan measurable sets is Jordan measurable, does it mean it fails for Jordan?

Comment: How do you define Jordan content to an unbounded set?

Comment: our definition of Jordan? for jordan outer measure, we define it as $J^* (S)=\inf_{\mathcal C} \sum_{\mathcal R\in C} \mathrm{mes} (R)$, where the inf is taken over all the finite collections $\mathcal C$ of rectangles in $\mathbb R^n$ such that $S\subset \bigcup_{R\in \mathcal C} R$.

Comment: If $S$ is unbounded, how can you cover it by finitely many bounded rectangles?